# c# Parsing a flat file and editing which conist of hex code as seperator

Tags: c#, text-parsing

Hi Team,
                 I have a flat file with data init seperated by hexcode as Rows/columns I need to parse the file and inject an additional column with data.

e.g. EID1000ENAJohnJOBSalesMan>EID1001ENASmithJOBAnalyst> and soon.............

Assuming that in above scenario I need to inject Deptono as DEP10> what would be the best way to do this i.e. File IO has methods in c# or writing core code to achive the same, any sample\link\suggestion on this would be of gr8 help.

Comment: Just use `File IO`. There are a million links online discussing how to process text files using C#. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for you response. well I am aware typing File IO would fetch million of link. My intention was-if some one has worked on similar requirement they would share there experience\process they used in processing the similar requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are surely many ways to do it but I would do something like this.

Open the file for reading, and another file for writing.
Read the file line by line, compare the data to see if the record is the one you want, if it is change it and add that line to the new temp file, otherwise just copy the line to the temp file. In the end replace the old file with the new one. You will have to do this if the file is quite big, otherwise switch to a proper database like SqlLite.